# check value from custom listview if already exists

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, hashmap

I have two custom listview in the same activity. Then, second listview can get the itemValue and itemID selected from the first listview. Then now, how do I check if the itemID is already exists in the second listview? Thanks in advance.

This is my second listview

```
private void listOrder(String itemValue, String itemID)
{   
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


    String quantity = "1";

    map.put(FOODID3, itemID);
    map.put(FOODNAME3, itemValue);  
    map.put(FOODQUANTITY3, quantity);

    LIST3.add(map);

    LISTORDER = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOrder);

    List3Adapter adapter = new List3Adapter(MainActivity.this, LIST3);
    LISTORDER.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    LISTORDER.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {

        }
    });
}
```

And this is the class of the listview

```
public class List3Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public List3Adapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d)
{
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }

    TextView foodID3 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.foodID3);
    TextView foodname3 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.foodName3);
    TextView foodquantity3 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.foodQuantity3);

    HashMap<String,String> food = new HashMap<String, String>();
    food = data.get(position);

    foodID3.setText(food.get(MainActivity.FOODID3));
    foodname3.setText(food.get(MainActivity.FOODNAME3));
    foodquantity3.setText(food.get(MainActivity.FOODQUANTITY3));

    return vi;
}
}
```

Comment: Where have you called listOrder method?

Comment: @Tamanna from the first listview of onItemClick

Comment: then what you get?? u can check for the key in hash map to check f the itemID is already exists

Comment: @Tamanna I can get the itemValue and itemID selected from the first listview, You means check it by using containskey?

Comment: Why you want to check?? If you want this check before adding data in adapter, out it in MainActviity..

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the key in hash map to check if the itemID is already exists or not

```
if(data.containsKey(itemID))
{
  // your code
}
```

where `data` is a `HashMap<String, String>` object

Comment: Sorry, actually I was confusing on doing this checking in my MainActivity or in my class. Do you have any example related on containskey suggest? Thanks!

Comment: You can check this according to ur need